# How do I customize an extended python class containing an object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to extend a class that contains member variables that are objects.  Is it possible to create/modify the member variable that is itself an object?  See my example below...hopefully that will clarify things:

```
class C1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x1 = 100
        self.y1 = 100
        self.z1 = 100

class C2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v2 = 200
        self.obj = C1()


class C3(C2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C3, self).__init__()
        # Here I'm adding a member variable a1
        self.a1 = "A1"
        # Want to do something like below, 
        # but this results in an error
        self.obj.x3 = 200


c = C3()
```

In my real case, I am doing an import of what is effectively class C1 and C2.  I need some way to customize/extend the member variable obj in C2.

Comment: This is a rather strange question, since in Python, *all member variables are always objects*. Indeed, *everything is an object*. Your question boils down to "can I modify member variables in derived classes". And the answer is yes, of course you can.

Comment: The problem is you never call `C2.__init__` in `C3`, so non of the instance variables are assigned. That is the source of your error.

Comment: My bad...thanks, that did it.